# update checkbox value from the form to database btu error occured

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with storing and updating checkboxes values.

PHP Code

```
<?php 
require ("****");
$id =$_REQUEST['id'];
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
mysql_select_db('registerforn');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regi_user WHERE id  = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
extract($_POST);
if(isset($save)){
$skills=implode("," , $skills);
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE regi_user SET emp_name ='$emp_name',email ='$email',gender ='$gender',interest='$interest' , skills='$skills' WHERE id = '$id'");
     $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
     header('location:display.php');
 }
 ?>
```

HTML Code

```
<tr><th>
    Option Subject</th>
 <th>
<?php 
$chkbox=$row['skills'];
$skills=explode("," , $chkbox);
?>
    <input <?php if(in_array("oops",$row)){echo "checked";}?> type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox"  name="skills[]" id="skills" value="oops">OOPS<br>   <!--class="myCheckBox"-->
    <input <?php if(in_array("pic",$row)){echo "checked";}?> type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox"   name="skills[]" id="skills" value="pic">Programin In C<br>
    <input <?php if(in_array("java",$row)){echo "checked";}?> type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox"  name="skills[]" id="skills" value ="java" >JAVA<br>
    <input <?php if(in_array("ds",$row)){echo "checked";}?> type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox"  name="skills[]" id="skills" value="ds">DS
    <div id="msg55"></div>
    <!--<div class="msg22"></div>class="myCheckBox"-->
 </th>
</tr>
```

This is My Update Page. So That Time Occurred problem
**Error Page**

[image]

Comment: You call both $_REQUEST['id'] and $_POST['id'].  Neither one of them are defined in the code that you posted.

Comment: $_REQUEST['id'] and $_POST['id'] dont have problem this statement. i have problem in <?php 
$chkbox=$row['skills'];
$skills=explode("," , $chkbox);
?> here.

Comment: what does echo $row['skills'] show?

Comment: i am get checkbox values using impode function so that time i am using this and please you should check my php code. $skills=implode("," , $skills);
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE regi_user SET emp_name ='$emp_name',email ='$email',gender ='$gender',interest='$interest' , skills='$skills' WHERE id = '$id'");
     $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

Comment: You did not answer my question. Echo out $row['skills'] on your screen and tell me what it says.

Comment: get a value in row wise.

Comment: Copy and paste the value you got into the comment box so I can read it please.

Comment: if (!$result) 
  {
  die("Error: Data not found..");
  } 
   
if(isset($row))

{
    $id=$row['id'] ;
    $emp_name=$row['emp_name'] ;
    $email= $row['email'] ;     
    $gender=$row['gender'] ;
    $interest=$row['interest'] ;
    //$chk=$row['chk'] ;
    //$chk   =   implode(",",$row['skills']);

 }